# How to define a macro as empty string?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

```
#define TEST
```

How to make TEST as empty string in the source file?

Comment: Do you mean an empty string literal or an empty `std::string` ?

Comment: Or an empty sequence of preprocessor tokens, in which case what you have is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Should I see an issue of empty text macro propagated throughout a source file as something normal ? 
For specific cases e.g in windows programming with use of wide characters

`#define EMPTY_TEXT L""`

or

`#define EMPTY_TEXT _T("")`

or

`#define EMPTY_TEXT TEXT("")`

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is an empty C string:

```
#define TEST ""
```